# How to have identical database model connected?

Tags: sql, rdbms

Sorry for the obscure title but it's diffucult to explain. Say we have two databases with a completely identical model and a table in each which stores the user information, but now we want the user info to be always the same, in both of the db's. You could argue why not use the same db, but there are several other tables storing data which can change the program flow of the server and I want some tables to be completely split, table1 (db1) should not be able to know whats inside table2 (db2) although they are connected in the model, however, it should see whats inside table2 (db1). Is there a good solution to "link" them through the user tables? I don't consider inserting the same data into both the databases a good solution because there is theoretically no limit of how many models I have. Maybe just use a table prefix?

Comment: " I don't consider inserting the same data into both the databases a good solution": Isn't this what you want?

Comment: Well, I could but consider having 20 of these databases. It would be very inconvenient updating them over and over again whenever there is a change, not mentioning the performance.

Comment: So why not have these "common" tables in a separate and single database?

Comment: other tables which are individual refer to them, for all I know you can't have relations between tables in different db's

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: It's more of an educational question, doesn't really matter, mysql, postgres or whatever

Comment: I personally feel a poor design decision has come back to haunt you. I am afraid but data replication or common database with tables is probably only solution I can think of. I am not thinking of linked server at this point.

Comment: @danish Separation of customer data by law can quickly lead to such designs